# angular REST API http 302 status error Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I use **Laravel 5.8** and **Angular 8**.
I call a POST API and in the API controller return response with Location to other website but give an error :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.example.com. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

my controller

```
class InvoiceController extends Controller{
    public $successStatus = 200;
    public function addInvoice(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'id'=>'required',
            'title'=>'required',
            'price'=>'required',
            'price_state'=>'required',
        ]
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->first()], 400);
    }
    $input['id']= $request['id'];
    $input['title']= $request['title'];
    $input['price']= (int)$request['price'];
    $input['price_state']= $request['price_state'];
    $invoice = (new Invoice)->amount( $input['price']);
    $invoice->detail(['course' =>$input['title']]);

    return Payment::callbackUrl('http://localhost:4200/preInvoice/'.$input['id'].'/'.$input['title'])->purchase(
        $invoice,
        function($driver, $transactionId) {
            // we can store $transactionId in database
        }
    )->pay();
}
}
```

I use **CORS** middleware in Laravel

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'HEAD,POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
    ];

    if($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return \response('', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;
}
```

this is my http response
[image]

Comment: Your API endpoint is http://localhost:4200? and you are calling that endpoint from http://localhost:8000?
If you are calling with Authorization header then you need to explicitly set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

In your case, the location seems different. That's why * (asterisk) won't work here mostly.

Comment: @ShahariaAzam my api work is true with orgin * However i changed * to localhost:4200 but this problem was for other url please check option url